# android ksoap call xmlpullparser exception

Tags: android, exception, ksoap2, xmlpullparser

I have used ***ksoap2*** to call my SOAP service. It works fine in **android2.2**, but when the same code runs in **android2.3.3** onwards it throws an exception in the following line.

```
http_transport_se.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

The exception thrown, as follows.

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT �������������[ێG...@1:255 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4057acc8)
```

Note that no parameters are needed to call this method. Please help. :(

Comment: what does your wsdl look like? more details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not solve this problem, ksoap2 API have issues running in multiple platforms. So I have implemented the SOAP service without using any API and went Native.

This [link](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-calling-web-services/) helped me make a call to my web service. And [here](http://www.validwsdl.com/) you can find how your SOAP request/response looks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using another version of the library. Switching the version from 2.6.5 to 2.6.4 solved the problem for me.